# Win7, path is (none) when running a shortcut

Tags: windows-7

Sometimes win7 enters a mode, such that when I double click a desktop shortcut the application is run with path=(none) (which usually causes it to exit with an error, since it cannot find necessary files in the path). If I run instead cmd, the path is fine, and running the app from the cmd works fine as well. 
Any ideas?

Comment: is this ANY shortcut run from the desktop, or only a specific shortcut?  Do shortcuts not on the desktop work as expected? Did you set a correct "Run in" path for the shortcut?

Comment: Standard shortcut with default settings. Probably it doesn't matter if it's on the desktop or not. After restarting the computer the problem was resolved (until next time), so I cannot do more tests.